# Not able to make the CSS3 animation as continuous

Tags: css, css-animations, translate-animation

I am following one blog to understand the CSS3 animations.  I wanted to do marquee effect vertically using CSS3. I have followed [this example](https://www.quackit.com/html/html_editors/scratchpad/?example=/css/codes/marquees/scroll_vertically). But the my issue is why there is some delay to restart the animation? When scroll came to down, it is not starting immediately from the top. Some 2,3 seconds of delay is there. How to start the animation from top immediately after the scroll ends. I am attaching gif file here to understand much better.

Code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Example</title>

<!-- Styles --> 
<style>
.example3 {
 height: 200px; 
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
.example3 h3 {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 /* Starting position */
 -moz-transform:translateY(-100%);
 -webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);   
 transform:translateY(-100%);
 /* Apply animation to this element */  
 -moz-animation: example3 15s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: example3 15s linear infinite;
 animation: example3 15s linear infinite;
}
/* Move it (define the animation) */
@-moz-keyframes example3 {
 0%   { -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); }
 100% { -moz-transform: translateY(100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes example3 {
 0%   { -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); }
 100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); }
}
@keyframes example3 {
 0%   { 
 -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 transform: translateY(-100%);      
 }
 100% { 
 -moz-transform: translateY(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 transform: translateY(100%); 
 }
}
</style>

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="example3">
<h3>Scrolling down... </h3>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your animation starting immidiatly, but you are start at position -100%.

If you want to start from top, then change every keyframes to 0 from -100%.
If You want to roll down immidiately from top, then try to change it equal with your text line height (-50px).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <title>Example</title>

<!-- Styles -->
<style>
  .example3 {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }
  .example3 h3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    /* Starting position */
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px);
    transform: translateY(-50px);
    /* Apply animation to this element */
    -moz-animation: example3 15s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: example3 15s linear infinite;
    animation: example3 15s linear infinite;
  }
  /* Move it (define the animation) */
  @-moz-keyframes example3 {
    0% {
      -moz-transform: translateY(-50px);
    }
    100% {
      -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
    }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes example3 {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px);
    }
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    }
  }
  @keyframes example3 {
    0% {
      -moz-transform: translateY(-50px); /* Firefox bug fix */
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px); /* Firefox bug fix */
      transform: translateY(-50px);
    }
    100% {
      -moz-transform: translateY(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
      -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
      transform: translateY(100%);
    }
  }
</style>

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="example3"><h3>Scrolling down...</h3></div>
```

Comment: Still there is some delay between end and start

Answer (score 1):

You need to reajust the movements.

I have set 3 examples with the solution that you have: The first position, the second one, and the animation.

And then, another 3 examples with a possible solution, with the initial state, the final one, and the animation.

I have removed the overflow: hidden, and colored the element semitransparent, so that it's easily seen what is happening

```css
.example {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.example h3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 255, 0.7);
}

#ex1 h3 {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
#ex2 h3 {
    transform: translateY(100%);
}

#ex3 h3 {
  animation: example 15s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes example {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
}
#ex4 h3 {
    top: -32px;
}
#ex5 h3 {
    top: -20px;
    transform: translateY(100%);
}
#ex6 h3 {
  animation: example2 15s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes example2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-32px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(calc(-20px + 100%));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="example" id="ex1">
  <h3>Scrolling</h3>
</div>
<div class="example" id="ex2">
  <h3>Scrolling</h3>
</div>
<div class="example" id="ex3">
  <h3>Scrolling</h3>
</div>
<div class="example" id="ex4">
  <h3>Scrolling</h3>
</div>
<div class="example" id="ex5">
  <h3>Scrolling</h3>
</div>
<div class="example" id="ex6">
  <h3>Scrolling</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using **CSS Position**

By setting the parent container to relative and the child element to absolute, you can get the marquee effect without delays.

Below is a sample snippet do further demonstrate what do you want to happen in your marquee. Here, we used the **position: relative;** to the parent class *wrap* to make the **position: absolute;** of the marquee element *h4* recognize it as its parent.

Going to the **keyframes**, we set the position of *h4* to **top: 0%** to make it stick above the container at the start and **top: calc(100% - 18px);** on its peak.

> Why do we need to use **calc()** here?

- Basically adding just 100% to its peak position will overflow the marquee outside the parent element, causing weird behaviour.

> Why **calc(100% - 18px)**?

- 18px is the default font size of every text you add into an element, and we set the css of the marquee to **padding: 0; and margin: 0** to remove extra spaces inside and outside that makes the marquee looks like we have starting delay because we only see the blank spaces unoccupied by the text inside the marquee;

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  background: gray;
}

.wrap h4 {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    top: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    top: calc(100% - 18px);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    top: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    top: calc(100% - 18px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    top: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    top: calc(100% - 18px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <h4>Oopsie</h4>
</div>
```